# Find filename with highest integer in name

Tags: python, csv, filenames

### Summary

If FCR_Network_Coordinates_0 and FCR_Network_Coordinates_2 exists, it should write to file FCR_Network_Coordinates_3 and not to FCR_Network_Coordinates_1

### Details

I have the following problem:

I want to write a new csv file, if it does not exist and increase the extension number if some file was found in directory. But if as an example a file with number extension "1" exists, and one with "3", but none with "2", it should write the next file with "4". So it should add 1 to the highest number extension

My code so far is:

```
    index = 0
    while os.path.exists('../FCR_Network_Coordinates_'+ str(index) + '.csv'):
        index+=1            
    with open('../FCR_Network_Coordinates_'+str(index)+'.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
        for key, value in sparse1.items():
            writer.writerow(['{:.1f}'.format(t) for t in key]+value)
```

**EDIT**

It should also work for paths where parameters are added in path name

```
 "../FCR_Network_Coordinates_"+"r_"+radius+"x_"+x+"y_"+y+"z_"‌​+z+"fcr_"+fcr_size+"‌​_"+new_number+".csv"
```

could look like:

```
FCR_Network_Coordinates_radius_3_x_0.3_y_0.3_z_2_fcr_2_1.csv
```

**EDIT2**

Furthermore if there are other parameters in the filename it should not look to the highest number of all files, but of the highest number of that file that have these parameters too

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: If FCR_Network_Coordinates_0 and FCR_Network_Coordinates_2 exists, it should write to file FCR_Network_Coordinates_3 and not to FCR_Network_Coordinates_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work for you:

```
import glob
import os

# .....

existing_matches = glob.glob('../FCR_Network_Coordinates_*.csv')

if existing_matches:
    used_numbers = []
    for f in existing_matches:
        try:
            file_number = int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0].split('_')[-1])
            used_numbers.append(file_number)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    save_number = max(used_numbers) + 1
else:
    save_number = 1

with open('../FCR_Network_Coordinates_{}.csv'.format(save_number), 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
    for key, value in sparse1.items():
        writer.writerow(['{:.1f}'.format(t) for t in key] + value)
```

`glob` finds all files with names similar to your pattern, where `*` is used as a wildcard.

We then use `os.path` to manipulate each filename and work out what the number in the name is:

- `os.path.basename()` gets us just the filename - e.g. `'FCR_Network_Coordinates_1.csv'`
- `os.path.splitext()` splits the file name (`'FCR_Network_Coordinates_1'`) from the extension (`'.csv'`). Taking the element at index 0 gets us the filename rather than the extension
- splitting this based on `'_'` splits this every time there is an `'_'` - resulting in a list of `['FCR', 'Network', 'Coordinates', '1']`. Taking the index -1 gets us the last entry in this list, i.e. the 1.
- we have to wrap this as an `int()` to be able to apply numeric operations to it.

We also catch an error in case there is some filename using letters rather than numbers after the underscore. Then, we take the max of the numbers found and add one. If no numbers have been found, we use 1 for the filename.

EDIT:
In response to the question update, we just need to alter our `glob` and the final name we write to - the `glob` changes to:

```
existing_matches = glob.glob('../FCR_Network_Coordinates_r_{}_x_{}_y_{}_z_{}_fcr_{}_*.csv'.format(
    radius, x, y, z, fcr_size))
```

and the file opening line changes to:

```
with open('../FCR_Network_Coordinates_r_{}_x_{}_y_{}_z_{}_fcr_{}_{}.csv'.format(
        radius, x, y, z, fcr_size, save_number), 'wb') as csv_file:
```

Comment: Nice thank you, what does "x = int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0].split('_')[-1])" do?

Comment: @Varlor edited an explanation into the answer

Comment: I edited my question a little bit, maybe you could look at it :9, thank you for the explanation!!:)

Comment: But now with your explanation i think it nevertheless should work :D

Comment: @Varlor I've updated again. String formatting should make inserting your variables a little neater rather than using `+` all the time

Comment: Thank you for your effort! :)

Comment: hmm, when running the programm the second time it alwyas overwrites the created file

Comment: what do you mean 'the second time'?

Comment: If i run the program again, it does not write to a new file, but overwrites the file, that was created in the run before, edited something to the question

Comment: You need to make sure that you calculate `save_number` for every "run".

Comment: ah i think i see a mistake. In your function there is the variable "x", which is also in the filewrite function

Comment: @Varlor Ah! Should've spotted that. Let me fix it.

Comment: And your code already does what i need for my 2nd edit:) Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Your code will stop searching at file "2" (if "2" does not exist)  even if there are files "3" & "4"

You need to use `glob` to get all files that match your pattern

```
import glob
import re
files=glob.glob("../FCR_Network_Coordinates_*.csv")
```

Next remove all the nondigits from your file names

```
file_nums=[]
for i, s in enumerate(files):

    num_str = re.search("(\d+).csv$",  files[i]) #capture only integer before ".csv" and EOL
    file_nums.append(parseInt(num_str.group(1)))  #convert to number

new_number=max(file_nums)+1 #find largest and increment
```

Sort the list of files to find which has the highest number.

Comment: Hey! Thank you :). I get that error "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal". Do you know why? Best regards

Comment: This came up while I was writing my answer, +1 for using `glob`

Comment: @Varlor typo in code, fixed now

Comment: I presume you mean to append the number to `file_nums` instead of assigning.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, thanks

Comment: But this would not work if other numbers would be in the path name like if i add some paramters which could change from run to run and are all numbers? Something like: "../FCR_Network_Coordinates_"+"r_"+radius+"x_"+x+"y_"+y+"z_"+z+"fcr_"+fcr_size+"_"+new_number+".csv" could look like:

FCR_Network_Coordinates_radius_3_x_0.3_y_0.3_z_2_fcr_2_1.csv

Comment: @Ken edited and added it to question

Comment: @Varlor changed reg ex to only capture integer just before ".csv"

Comment: Thank you for your effort! :)

Comment: Ok it works fine!, i have to use int() instead of ParseInt. But there is something tricky. If there are other parameters in the filename it should not look to the hghest number of all files, but of the highest number of that file that have these parameters too

Comment: edited to question